# count() methos is deporecated and the countDocuments is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

On a cursor object (**FindCursor** according to the latest driver version [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/Next/classes/FindCursor.html)), I want to get the number of returned **documents** after using the `find` method in **MongoDB**. I used the **count** method but it turned out it is a depreciated method.

Here is the code:

```
const users = userCollection.find({age: 25});
console.log("The number of users is " + users.count());
```

And here is the error message that I got :

```
(node:17824) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: cursor.count is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version, please use `collection.estimatedDocumentCount` or `collection.countDocuments` instead
```

I checked the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/), and here is what I found in the **note section** :

> MongoDB drivers compatible with the 4.0 features deprecate their
> respective cursor and collection count() APIs in favor of new APIs
> that corresponds to countDocuments() and estimatedDocumentCount(). For
> the specific API names for a given driver, see the driver API
> documentation.

I tried both **countDocuments** and **estimatedDocumentCount**, but unfortunately, none of them worked and I got this error message :

```
TypeError: users.countDocuments is not a function
```

In the [FindCursor documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/Next/classes/FindCursor.html), these methods do not show in the list of class methods, and that made me more confused because I can neither use count since it is deprecated nor these 2 methods since they are not available.

How can get the number of returned documents in a cursor in such a case?

ps: I am using the latest [MongoDB package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) version (5.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `countDocuments` function should be executed on the collection, not on the `find` result. So:

```
let count = userCollection.countDocuments({age: 25});
```